# Does "bup index --clear" cause data loss?

Tags: linux, backup

I did "bup index" with some arguments, but during "bup save" realised that I included some very large folders that I do not want to back up.

I cancelled "bup save" and modified my "bup index" command line to exclude those folders.

Do I have to run "bup index --clear"? "bup index" otherwise seems to want to merge existing and new indices, but I want want to remove those folders.

I am concerned that "bup index --clear" will alter the filesystem index in the BUPDIR, the man page is not very clear on that (no pun intended).

Answer (score 1):

I was told on IRC that "bup index --clear" is harmless. It will clear the file list to be backed up next, not anything on the backup directory.